One journalist makes $2$ typos per article, second $3.2$ and third $4$. Prob. that a random article contains at least 2 typos. Solution verification.
The newspaper employs three journalists: A, B and C.
A makes an average of $2$ typos per article, for B and C the averages are $3.2$ and $4$, respectively.
The Monday edition of the newspaper contains fifteen articles:

$4$, written by A,
$5$, written by B,
$6$, written by C.

Calculate the probability that a randomly selected article from this issue contains at least two typos.

I think that we can model the number of typos in an article using the Poisson distribution.

A: $\lambda_1=2$ typos per article
B: $\lambda_2=3.2$ typos per article
C: $\lambda_3=4$ typos per article

Probability of an Article from Each Journalist:

$\mathbb{P}(\text{article was written by A}) = \frac{4}{15}$
$\mathbb{P}(\text{article was written by B}) = \frac{5}{15}$
$\mathbb{P}(\text{article was written by C}) = \frac{6}{15}$

For a Poisson-distributed random variable $X$ with rate $λ$, the probability of $X=k$ typos is:
$$\mathbb{P}(X=k)= \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$$
We need to calculate $\mathbb{P}(X \geq 2)$ for each journalist:
$$\mathbb{P}(X \geq 2) = 1 − \mathbb{P}(X=0) − \mathbb{P}(X=1)$$
For A:

$\mathbb{P}(X_1​ = 0) = e^{-2}$
$\mathbb{P}(X_1 ​= 1) = 2e^{-2}$
$\mathbb{P}(X_1​ \geq 2) = 1 − e^{−2} −2e^{−2} = 1−3e^{−2}$

For B:

$\mathbb{P}(X2​=0) = e^{-3.2}$
$\mathbb{P}(X2​=0) = 3.2e^{-3.2}$
$\mathbb{P}(X_1​ \geq 2) = 1 − e^{-3.2} − 3.2e^{-3.2} = 1 − 4.2e^{−3.2}$

For C:

$\mathbb{P}(X3​=0) = e^{-4}$
$\mathbb{P}(X3​=1) = 4e^{-4}$
$\mathbb{P}(X3​≥2) = 1 − e^{−4} − 4e^{−4} = 1 − 5e^{−4}$

Therefore the probability is equal to:
$$\frac{4}{15}(1−3e^{−2}) + \frac{5}{15}(1 − 4.2e^{−3.2}) + \frac{6}{15}(1 − 5e^{−4})$$
Is that correct?

That seems a sensible approach

Thank you, just wanted to make sure!
